# How to create multiple levels with Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, levels

I'm creating a simple puzzle game that uses Cocos2d and Box2d but I'm struggling to find any documentation on how to organise levels.

The game is similar to Cut the Rope in structure, it has multiple fixed size levels with changing Box2d assets.

Currently my mainGame.m file contains my HUD and methods for creating obstacles. Would the best answer be to call some sort of .plist file for each level that lists the assets to be created, and their respective position, then use a for loop to reference the method in the mainGame.m file?

Or could I create a level class on a seperate xxxxxx.m file that references the methods in my mainGame.m?

I apologise if this is vague/hard to understand, I'm very confused at the moment and not sure how to move forward :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few possibilities come to mind...

- Have either a separate CCScene instance for each of your levels or a separate CCLayer for each of your levels.
- Another possibility is having a custom class which just holds metadata about each level.  You than re-create all your level data on a single CCLayer instance from a single game scene.  This is what we are doing for [Mega Jump](http://getsetgames.com/games/mega-jump/).

As painful as it might be I would not get into the fine details of storing metadata for your level in a plist file.  Hard code values for any static placement of UI or other components you need to do.  Likely your time is better spent refining the game itself.  Hopefully some of those ideas are useful to you.  Certainly let me know if anything doesn't make sense or if you want me to go in depth into one of those items a bit more.

Comment: I'd really like if you explained it a little bit more. Espacially what you are saying about not storing the metadata in a plist file. Until now I did it like this, because I think it's the easiest way. How do you do it?

Comment: Thanks Rob, really useful information, and I'm glad you recommend not mucking around with plist's :p Both avenues seem a good choice.

Comment: IF you could go into a bit more detail about how you arrange the metadata for each level that would be great. For example are you using arrays to store information about each 'obstacle'?

Comment: @Sandro Meier I should correct my explanation.  I think using a plist is a great way to organize data for your game but if you are just starting out creating a game I think more priority should be placed on the game instead of some level loading code for the game.

Comment: @Alex Use whichever data structure you think is appropriate for your game.  Arrays, dictionaries, lists, etc. choose whichever is best for your situation.  Since you are using Cocos2D I would suggest trying to make use of CCArray where appropriate.  It is optimized to work with the Cocos2D engine.  If you do have a specific question about a particular situation in your design certainly I would be happy to offer any feedback I am able to.

Comment: @Rob Segal ah ok. Thank you for the explanation. I did it the same way you do. Create plists and create the layers from these plists... ;-)

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot, time to get stuck in! Thanks for pointing out the CCArray, missed that.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome.  I would also recommend posting questions in the future on the Cocos2D forums (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/).  Although their user base is not as large as Stack Overflow it is much more focused on the problems you would likely be encountering.

Answer (score 1):

well... the easiest way will be to use LevelSVG so that you can draw the levels in a SVG graphics editor and import them. If you can pay little price then LevelSVG is great.

Comment: As far as design is concerned, I would never code levels for a game like this. I will create a level factory that takes an XML or PList file parse it to create box2d bodies and cocos2d layer or scene and I in my Main Game I will just call [MyLevelFactory nextLevel] or something like [MyLevelFactory levelWithFile:@"levelXX.xml"] which gives me a layer or scene for that Level. And I will just define these levels in XML or some other tool. So that I can create new levels quickly without writing Objective-C code.

Comment: True LevelSVG would probably be the easiest.